# Neo4j 2.2 installation and upgrade from 2.1.5 under linux

Tags: neo4j

Just not quite sure what I've been doing wrong here.
I had the `neo4j` database `2.1.5` working fine under linux(except being slow). so I tried to `upgrade` to `2.2` version. 
These are the step I took:

```
 1. stop 2.1.5
 2. copy from 2.1.5/data/graph.db to 2.2/data/graph.db
 3. allow-store-upgrade=true
 4. start 2.2 by using command ./bin/neo4j start
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to start within 120 seconds.Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

I've been on it for a while now. any suggestion what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

This is the end of my `messages.log` file :

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:82) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0-M02.jar:2.2.0-M02]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:159) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0-M02.jar:2.2.0-M02]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0-M02.jar:2.2.0-M02]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0-M02.jar:2.2.0-M02]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:556) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0-M02.jar:2.2.0-M02]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:466) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0-M02.jar:2.2.0-M02]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.0-M02.jar:2.2.0-M02]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: what is in ./2.2/data/graph.db/messages.log?

Comment: @DaveBennett thx for bringing messages.log to my attention. PS I've updated my question

Comment: @DaveBennett dude, u saved my ass here. hehe. that I just rerun the old one and made sure it was stopped properly then ran the new one. it just worked :D